# `\DeclareMathOperator` at the beginning of a comment disables some link parsing

Tags: bug, mathjax, comments, hyperlinks, markdown

In a comment of the form `$\DeclareMathOperator\a{a}$Here's a [link](http://mathoverflow.net) and [another link](http://mathoverflow.net) $\a$`, neither link is parsed; in a comment of the form `$\DeclareMathOperator\a{a}$Here's a [link](http://mathoverflow.net)$\DeclareMathOperator\a{a}$ $\a$ and [another link](http://mathoverflow.net)`, the second link is parsed and the first is not; and in a comment of the form `Here's a [link](http://mathoverflow.net)$\DeclareMathOperator\a{a}$ and [another link](http://mathoverflow.net) $\a$`, both links are parsed.

Comment: @MartinSleziak, thanks!  I tried to guess at a minimal test case from some that had happened to me in the wild, and I guessed wrong.  I posted a few more variants beneath your comment.  It seems from a few tests that it only happens when `\DeclareMathOperator` is at the beginning, and only when `\a` is actually used, and that the affected span is between the declaration and the use.  I updated the sample text accordingly.

Comment: $\DeclareMathOperator\a{a}$Here's a [link](http://mathoverflow.net) $\a$ and [another link](http://mathoverflow.net).

Comment: So it seems that the problem can be replicated also on meta, not only on main. (I am mentioning this because of [the first version of this question](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/revisions/4786/1) saying that "apparently the problem does not occur on MMO".) In the previous comment I have posted this: `$\DeclareMathOperator\a{a}$Here's a [link](http://mathoverflow.net) $\a$ and [another link](http://mathoverflow.net).`

Answer (score 2):

This answer is intended for testing.

Please include the source code used in the comments into the answer — so that we can check when the link works and when it doesn't.

- [1](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/4786/on-mathoverflow-declaremathoperator-in-comments-disables-following-link-pars#comment24280_4788) `$\DeclareMathOperator{\Hom}{Hom}$ [link](http://mathoverflow.net) $\Hom (U\times V,W)$ and [another link](http://mathoverflow.net).`
- [2](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/4786/on-mathoverflow-declaremathoperator-in-comments-disables-following-link-pars#comment24281_4788) `$\DeclareMathOperator{\Hom}{Hom}$ [link](http://mathoverflow.net) $\Hom$ and [another link](http://mathoverflow.net).`
- [3](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/4786/on-mathoverflow-declaremathoperator-in-comments-disables-following-link-pars#comment24282_4788) `$\DeclareMathOperator{\R}{\mathbb R}$[link](http://mathoverflow.net) $\R$ and [another link](http://mathoverflow.net).`
- [4](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/4786/on-mathoverflow-declaremathoperator-in-comments-disables-following-link-pars#comment24283_4788) `$\DeclareMathOperator{\R}{\mathbb R}$ [link](http://mathoverflow.net) $\R$ and [another link](http://mathoverflow.net).` — The difference between this comment and the one before is just the space added before the first link.
- [5](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/4786/on-mathoverflow-declaremathoperator-in-comments-disables-following-link-pars#comment24284_4788) `A $\DeclareMathOperator\a{a}$[link](http://mathoverflow.net) $\a$ and [another link](http://mathoverflow.net).`
- [6](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/4786/on-mathoverflow-declaremathoperator-in-comments-disables-following-link-pars#comment24285_4788) `A [link](http://mathoverflow.net) $\DeclareMathOperator\a{a}$and [another link](http://mathoverflow.net) $\a$.`  The problem seems to concern parsing of links between a `\DeclareMathOperator` with no following space and the invocation of that math operator, wherever they occur in the comment.
- [7](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/4786/on-mathoverflow-declaremathoperator-in-comments-disables-following-link-pars#comment24286_4788) `$\DeclareMathOperator\a{a}$A [link](http://mathoverflow.net) and [another link](http://mathoverflow.net) $\a$.`
- [8](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/4786/declaremathoperator-at-the-beginning-of-a-comment-disables-some-link-parsing/4788#comment24289_4788) `$\newcommand{\R}{\mathbb R}$[link](http://mathoverflow.net) $\R$ and [another link](http://mathoverflow.net) - this one uses "newcommand" rather than DeclareMathOperator`
- [9](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/4786/declaremathoperator-at-the-beginning-of-a-comment-disables-some-link-parsing/4788#comment24290_4788) `$\def\R{\mathbb R}$[link](http://mathoverflow.net) $\R$ and [another link](http://mathoverflow.net) - this one uses "def" rather than DeclareMathOperator`
- [10](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/4786/declaremathoperator-at-the-beginning-of-a-comment-disables-some-link-parsing/4788#comment24292_4788) `$\let\vp\varphi$[link](http://mathoverflow.net) $\vp$ and [another link](http://mathoverflow.net) - this one uses "let" rather than DeclareMathOperator`

Comment: $\DeclareMathOperator{\Hom}{Hom}$ [link](http://mathoverflow.net) $\Hom (U\times V,W)$ and [another link](http://mathoverflow.net).

Comment: $\DeclareMathOperator{\Hom}{Hom}$ [link](http://mathoverflow.net) $\Hom$ and [another link](http://mathoverflow.net).

Comment: $\DeclareMathOperator{\R}{\mathbb R}$[link](http://mathoverflow.net) $\R$ and [another link](http://mathoverflow.net).

Comment: $\DeclareMathOperator{\R}{\mathbb R}$ [link](http://mathoverflow.net) $\R$ and [another link](http://mathoverflow.net).

Comment: A $\DeclareMathOperator\a{a}$[link](http://mathoverflow.net) $\a$ and [another link](http://mathoverflow.net).

Comment: A [link](http://mathoverflow.net) $\DeclareMathOperator\a{a}$and [another link](http://mathoverflow.net) $\a$.

Comment: $\DeclareMathOperator\a{a}$A [link](http://mathoverflow.net) and [another link](http://mathoverflow.net) $\a$.

Comment: $\newcommand{\R}{\mathbb R}$[link](http://mathoverflow.net) $\R$ and [another link](http://mathoverflow.net) - this one uses "newcommand" rather than DeclareMathOperator

Comment: $\def\R{\mathbb R}$[link](http://mathoverflow.net) $\R$ and [another link](http://mathoverflow.net) - this one uses "def" rather than DeclareMathOperator

Comment: $\let\vp\varphi$[link](http://mathoverflow.net) $\vp$ and [another link](http://mathoverflow.net) - this one uses "let" rather than DeclareMathOperator